# ¿como puedo controlar en python si un archivo se ha descargado para generar un log y enviar un email?

Tags: python, programación-bajo-nivel

por ejemplo en linux se controlarlo,, seria despues de descargar el archivo

```
if $? -eq0 
then
    echo "El archivo se ha descargado correctamente" | mail root
else
    echo "Ha habido un error, no se a descargado el archivo" | mail root
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la librería urllib y comprobar el código de respuesta. Te adjunto ejemplo.

Estoy usando la versión 3.6.6 de python, aunque también es compatible para versiones posteriores.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

#La url del fichero que quieres descargar

url = 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-512.png'
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    code = response.getcode()
    if (code == 200):
        logging.info('El fichero se ha descargado correctamente')
    else:
        print("Algo ha salido mal, no se ha descargado el fichero.")
except:
    logging.debug("Algo ha salido mal")
```

Para el envío de mensajes por e-mail puedes utilizar esta [guía](https://librosweb.es/libro/python/capitulo-14/envio-de-e-mail-desde-python.html):

Y simplemente lo envías después del código 200.

Espero que sirva de ayuda! :)

Comment: el archivo que descargo es de un servidor via ftp

Comment: Aunque sea un archivo ftp tiene que dar una respuesta de salida.

Comment: Puedes utilizar esta librería: "from ftplib import FTP".

Comment: vale entonces si el archivo que descargo es via Ftp, entiendo que es el mismo codigo que me has puesto menos la linea de url=    y la linea de response=

Comment: Es parecido, modifica los valores que se adapten a tus preferencias.